# Custom Shell in C: How do I execute a custom signal handler when I type Control C and then Control Z?

Tags: c, linux, shell, operating-system, signals

I am creating my own shell in C (similar to Bash), and right now I want to be able to run all processes in foreground only mode. To do that, I have to first listen for the command ^c^z (control C then control Z). Right now, my program is written so that if there is no process to terminate, typing in ^c in the shell simply just prints ^c to the terminal. See example output below.

```
: sleep 10
^Cterminated by signal 2
: ^C
:
```

How do I handle the condition to detect when BOTH ^c^z are pressed as shown below?

```
: ^C^Z
Entering foreground-only mode (& is now ignored)
```

Entry point of my Main function where I call signal is below. I am using SIG_IGN because the main program should ignore when control C is pressed.

```
void my_handler(sig_atomic_t signal)
{

    printf("terminated by signal %d\n", signal);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    char shellInput[2048];
    int processStatus;
    while (strncmp(shellInput, QUIT, strlen(QUIT)) != 0)
    {
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
        printf(": ");
        fgets(shellInput, 2048, stdin);
        char *command = strtok(shellInput, " \n");
        if (strncmp(command, "ls", strlen("ls")) == 0)
        {
            command = strtok(NULL, " ");
            if (command == NULL)
            {
                // No argument after ls
                int childStatus;
                pid_t spawnPid = fork();

                switch (spawnPid)
                {
                case -1:
                    perror("fork()\n");
                    exit(1);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    // This is the child process where we will call the ls function
                    ls();
                    perror("execv");
                    exit(2);
                    break;
                default:
                    // This is the parent process that takes control back after child process finishes.
                    spawnPid = waitpid(spawnPid, &childStatus, 0);
                    processStatus = (childStatus == 0) ? 0 : 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            else if (strncmp(shellInput, "sleep", strlen("sleep")) == 0)
            {
                char *secondsInput = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                char *backgroundProcess = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                if (backgroundProcess == NULL)
                {
                    // Run this sleep command in the foreground
                    int childStatus;
                    pid_t spawnPid = fork();
                    switch (spawnPid)
                    {
                    case -1:
                        perror("fork()\n");
                        exit(1);
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        // This is the child process where we will call the ls function
                        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
                        sleepFunc(secondsInput);
                        perror("execv");
                        exit(2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        // This is the parent process that takes control back after child process finishes.
                        signal(SIGINT, my_handler);
                        spawnPid = waitpid(spawnPid, &childStatus, 0);
                        testChildStatus(childStatus, &processStatus);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Basically I want to know how can I detect when ^c^z is pressed? Not sure why the following is happening either because I don't have any code that is handling SIGTSTP.

```
: ^C^Z
[1]  + 68614 suspended  ./smallsh
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "when ^c^z is pressed"?

Comment: Note: `while (strncmp(shellInput, QUIT, strlen(QUIT)) != 0)` invokes [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) on the first iteration as `shellInput` is not initialized.